# Laptop only boots windows

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Z585 and I want to replace the hard drive and install KDE Neon on it. I have tried putting in the new drive and it will not boot from a USB. The only working way to access the bios is to go to advanced startup and enter it through there. I cannot access it on boot whatsoever. When I do get into it I disabled secure boot and enabled legacy mode, then moved the USB to highest boot priority but when I save and restart it goes straight to Windows. I have Ubuntu dual booted and it ignores that too. It used to work and now the only way to boot into Ubuntu or any USB is in the advanced startup menu. Ubuntu works fine this way but when I select the USB it shows the KDE splash screen then goes blank. I tried using another computer to install KDE on the new hard drive but when it starts it does nothing. It only boots from the drive that it came with.

Comment: You contradict yourself. You write "now the only way to boot into Ubuntu or any USB is in the advanced startup menu"  yet you also wrote " it will not boot from a USB"   So which is it, you can boot USB or you can't? Also take the hard drive out when you experiment trying to figure out how to boot USB, that way you won't have to wait for it to go into windows when/if it fails to boot off USB.

Comment: @barlop it will boot from USB if it's selected in the windows advanced startup menu. It won't go past the KDE splash screen and the USB works fine on other computers. When I change the boot order in the bios it completely ignores it and boots into windows.

Comment: then wouldn't that indicate you are talking about two completely different problems in the same question?

Answer (score -1):

in regards to duel booting windoze and ubuntu: have you tried to re-build the master GRUB configuration file? Windoze is well known for trying to ignore linux. To re-build grub:

1 boot any linux version, USB, HDD, Floppy, whatever. 
2 In your linux, open a terminal (press **Ctrl + Alt + T** at the same time)
3 In the terminal type **sudo update-grub** , wait for the update to finish.
4 **Reboot** your computer.

*I really hope this helps.*

https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwje3NnFn5_ZAhXJoZQKHXWpA9MQFgg_MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F281119%2Fhow-do-you-run-update-grub&usg=AOvVaw3dbMwxS4wpt2Q4zKoN9N5i

Comment: It didn't work. Still have same issues.